# overflow y scroll on position fixed div shows double scrollbars

Tags: html, css

When I have an "overlay sidebar" type div with `position: fixed` coming in on the right side of a body (where there is also overflow content) I get double scrollbars.

I think what I would like is for the overlay div to "cover up" the body scroll bar, if this is possible. example on Chrome & Linux here [example on Chrome & Linux here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPuia.png) and example [js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/so31emcb/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the scrollbar of the body while keeping its functionality then you add this to your CSS

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Note: Hiding Scrollbar is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

A table element would achieve the desired layout result that you're looking for.  The Chrome browser does not immediately force scroll bars on table display (I'm not sure why) but it works.   Add `display: table;` to the `#sidebar` CSS.

```
body,
#sidebar {
  padding: 2rem;

}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
#sidebar {
  padding: 2rem;

}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
    <p>hello it's content content content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>hello it's sidebar content</p>
    <p>hello it's sidebar content</p>
    <p>hello it's sidebar content</p>
    <p>hello it's sidebar content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Your sidebar has too much content. That's why it's showing two scrollbar. If you don't want two scrollbar then you need to maintain the sidebar content.